mod_rewrite question for many virtual directories -most efficient code?
My current .htaccess is:
    RewriteEngine On

#Using THE_REQUEST for catching references and using them later on.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(content)/index\.php\?var=(.*?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/featured/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(content)/featured/(.*?)/?$ $1/index.php?var=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

This rewrites a URL called www.domain.com/content/index.php?var=xxx.php to www.domain.com/content/featured/doc
But I have other virtual dirs I want to display and the domain has a number of deeper directories for additional documents.
Question is what is the cleanest most efficient way to write the .htaccess code?
Example documents and paths
www.domain.com/legal/privacy.php  
                        rewrite to: www.domain.com/legal/privacy

www.domain.com/users/male/user.php?=ttt   
                        rewrite to:  www.domain.com/users/male/user

www.domain.com/game/build/nation/barracks/roster.php?var=name&&var2=device&var3=level 
                        rewrite to:   www.domain.com/game/build/nation/barracks/var/var2/var3

I probably have about 30 directories and subdirectories
Thanks
